# How fix a TypeError in this specific example with dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Some time ago I made a script to filter elements more than a specific value in a data frame(DF).
Now, I reuse this script to filter other values in a DF in a CSV file.
Here is a part of the file for you can see how it looks like:

```
Partition,Site,ES,EN,S,N,P[S],dS,dN,dN-dS,P [dN/dS > 1],P [dN/dS < 1],Total branch length
1,1,0,3.000000000000001,0,0,0,null,0,null,1,1,39.076790211622
1,2,0.5566572827464659,2.283438288771876,2.75,18.25,0.1959994897104366,4.940203039169632,7.992333355247175,0.07810596263277007,0.3385048004154001,0.8414604110057038,39.076790211622
...
```

Here is the data "parsing"  (only to look better for the post):

```
Partition   Site    ES  EN  S   N   P[S]    dS  dN  dN-dS   P [dN/dS > 1]   P [dN/dS < 1]   Total branch length

1   1   0   3.000000000000001   0   0   0   null    0   null    1   1   39.076790211622

1   2   0.5566572827464659  2.283438288771876   2.75    18.25   0.1959994897104366  4.940203039169632   7.992333355247175   0.07810596263277007 0.3385048004154001  0.8414604110057038  39.076790211622
```

Here is the script to filter the data:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DF with specific column names
df_S_SLAC = pd.read_csv("S_SLAC.csv",sep=",", names=['dN-dS',"P [dN/dS > 1]","P [dN/dS < 1]"])

# Filter all values <= value of interest and write a new file with the filtered values 
S_greather_than = (df_S_SLAC["dN-dS"] < 5) & (df_S_SLAC["P [dN/dS > 1]"] < 5) & (df_S_SLAC["P [dN/dS < 1]"] < 5)
df_S_SLAC.loc[S_greather_than]
df_S_SLAC.loc[S_greather_than].to_csv(".../S_SLAC_v1.csv")
```

So, this script gives me this error:

```
TypeError: ‘<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I understand this error partially because I can´t find why is wrong when trying to filter the data.
So, it´s possible to fix the issue or I could edit the input file or/and script?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: It looks like the values in your column are casted as string, you should convert them as int using `.astype(int)` on the column. Alternatively, define the type during data import in `read_csv`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you give me a small example of your idea? Please. I don´t understand completely how to incorporate it into my script. @mozway

Comment: I check the type of the data using `dtypes` and this function say me that                `dN-dS            object
P [dN/dS > 1]    object
P [dN/dS < 1]    object` maybe this data could be other data type. What do you thing? @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your error. You used `names` instead of `usecols` to filter your columns. This results in the text header being incorporated as data.

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("S_SLAC.csv",sep=",", usecols=['dN-dS',"P [dN/dS > 1]","P [dN/dS < 1]"])
```